# Coefficient of temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, electrical-resistance, approximations

Is the equation for the temperature dependence of a resistance based on experimental observations, or was it derived from a fundamental law or something?  What, therefore, are the limitations of the linear equation $R^{*}=R(1+\alpha\theta)$, where $\alpha$ is the coefficient of temperature variation?

Answer (score 0):

I see now that you are referring to the thermal coefficient of electrical resistance.. I would say that there must have been empirical observations, first.

The limit of linear approximations is generally that for a quantity$\ R $, the approximation $ R_0 + \partial R/\partial x * \Delta x $ only holds while $\Delta x $ small... In the case of metal/conductors I can propose you the homologous temperature $\ \tilde T \approx 0.4*T_{melt} [\rm K] $ as upper limit, and the critical superconductivity temperature $\ T_{crit.} $ as lower limit . $\ T_{crit.} $ varies strongly with material but is usually$\ << 90 \rm \ K $ .

These limits are again, empirically determined. But, we can explain explain them  within the theoretical framework. For the lower limit, $\ T_{crit.} $ is where thermal phonons are negligible allowing lattice modes to couple with elastic electron-lattice interaction. Secondly,$\ \tilde T $ is where thermal motility allows for diffusion to really move stuff around within a solid lattice, which gets in the way of most first order property relations in solids. ( ... I got to say that I'm relying mostly on my intuition, here)

Comment: I couldn't get how the relation between the coefficient and reference resistance established?dR/R=(alpha)dT.......was this whole equation established based on the experimental observation? Or it can be derived from some other equations?

Comment: It's the first order Taylor approximation... basically any temperature dependence follows such a linear law, while you're in highschool. ;-)